# Lock Universal Access preferences

Tags: macos

In OSX I am looking to try and lock the Universal Access preferences to help prevent those options from being enabled (color inversion, zoom, contrast, etc.).

Attempted to lock the Universal Access preference file but it doesn't seem to maintain the ability to not have the color inverted.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

How about disabling the shortcut keys?  It would take a rather more convluted series of actions to turn them on, than you'd expect to take by accident.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to first disable all the keyboard shortcuts related to it from *System Prefereces » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Universal Access*

[image]

Then, you can remove the preference pane for Universal Access entirely. Quit the System Preferences app, open up a Terminal and enter

```
cd /System/Library/PreferencePanes
sudo mv UniversalAccessPref.prefPane UniversalAccessPref.prefPane.disabled
```

It'll magically disappear next time you open *System Preferences*.

[image]

To undo that, you obviously have to:

```
cd /System/Library/PreferencePanes
sudo mv UniversalAccessPref.prefPane.disabled UniversalAccessPref.prefPane
```